# How to write a nested multi-level json in Apache Spark with Scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I have a DataFrame like this:

```
+-------------------+-------+------+--------------------+
|         col_1     |  col_2| col_3|               col_4|
+-------------------+-------+------+--------------------+
|a                  |b      |c     |                  14|
|a                  |e      |f     |                  32|
|k                  |z      |x     |                  15|
+-------------------+-------+------+--------------------+
```

I would like to convert the dataframe above to this json:

```json
{"a": {"b": {"c": 14}, "e": {"f": 32}}, "k": {"z": {"x": 15}}}
```

Is there any built-in function in Spark I can use? Or I have to write my own UDF/UDAF?

Comment: Do you want a column of that type, or you want the result as a json array ? Also which language you are using Scala, Python ... ?

Comment: I want the result as a json, but store in a string column. I use Scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider that you want to create a dataframe with one column and one row containing your json string.

You could do it this way:

```scala
df
  .withColumn("s", struct('col_2, map('col_3, 'col_4)))
  .groupBy("col_1")
  .agg(map_from_entries(collect_list('s)) as "s")
  .groupBy(lit(1))
  .agg(collect_list(struct('col_1, 's)) as "s")
  .select(to_json(map_from_entries('s)) as "json")
  .show(false)
```

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|json                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|{"k":{"z":{"x":"15"}},"a":{"b":{"c":"14"},"e":{"f":"32"}}}|
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

NB: If that's not exactly what you want, let me know and we'll iterate.